# Bootstrap: add row edit button at the top of table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to make a table and at the top of table i want to keep row edit button. When i select a row and then if i click edit button the one dialog box should appear which we use to edit the content in that row. I am using Java scripts function and not using any php code. please help me to give some hint in this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
      <div class ="container">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parameter Names</th>
                    <th>Parameter Values</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Carter</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Parker</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me in this because i searched so many web site but i did not any relevant information

Comment: And where is the Javascript code?

Comment: this is simple table which i want to edit. There is no javascript code. i want to add that functionality in this table either using java scripts or simple html

Comment: Check if this [link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-edit-and-delete-rows-of-a-html-table-with-jquery/26721) helps you. I think that providing you the answer is the bad way for you to learn. Because you didn't even tried a line of code to make what you want to do.

Comment: This example may help get you started too: http://www.bootply.com/lGD22UTzTp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample I found on [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion). It should point you to the right direction

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md'></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });

});
```